# CSC.exe throws "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException" when compiling

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am using Entity Framework 4.0

Upon creating a new class with just over 1k properties I get a problem after creating the migration package. When trying to compile the project I get Build Failed. "csc.exe has exited with code 255"

When looking more into the details I see this msg in the build log:

Using "Csc" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll".
1>Task "Csc"
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:...
1>
1>  Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(67,5): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code 255.

Obviously the Up() method in the migration script creates a really big CreateTable method. I assume that to be the problem. I'm not quite sure though.

Is it actually not possible to have a class with this many fields when using EF?

Update:
The model class is in a separate project and compiles fine.
The problem is with the migration method.

It's also autogenerated and looks something like this:

```
public partial class CustomClass : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.GeneratedClasses",
            c => new
                {
                    RowId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    RecordTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Prop1 = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    Prop2 = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    Prop3 = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
```

...

```
                    PropN= c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.RowId);

    }
```

Comment: 1k properties in a class?!? o_O

Comment: Indeed. Not something I do every day mind you.

Comment: if data is more then you would end up with out of memory exception...stack overflow exception mean there is cyclic call or recursive call which ends up  getting stack overflow excepion

Comment: I added the code to the question above. "..." = 1k more of the same.

Answer (score 2):

More than 1000 properties in a class seems too much to me, really!

That put aside, the issue is most likely not that. A `StackOverflowException` indicates endless recursion. There might be a EF field / property that references itself, thus creating an endless loop.

I suggest to disable a few fields, try if it compiles then, and keep doing that until you find the offending line.

Comment: Good suggestion. The properties are auto-generated though, and pure get; set; properties. No recursions.

Comment: An attribute might cause such an issue too.

Comment: I updated the question with sample of the generated code file from generated migration script